# HBase get scanner exception - "This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses"

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, protobuf-net

I am trying to run the following code:

```
Cluster cluster = new Cluster();
cluster.add("localhost", port_number);
Client client = new Client(cluster);
RemoteHTable table = new RemoteHTable(client, "my_table");
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setStartRow(startKey);
scan.setStopRow(endKey);
scan.addFamily(columnFamily);
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

but the last line throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses.
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.getUnknownFields(GeneratedMessage.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.protobuf.generated.ScannerMessage$Scanner.getSerializedSize(ScannerMessage.java:274)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.toByteArray(AbstractMessageLite.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.model.ScannerModel.createProtobufOutput(ScannerModel.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.client.RemoteHTable$Scanner.(RemoteHTable.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.client.RemoteHTable.getScanner(RemoteHTable.java:620)
    at com.amazon.cq.banyan.hbase.example.HBaseRestClient.main(HBaseRestClient.java:55)
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
    <version>0.94.18</version>
</dependency>
```

This happens also when trying to do a Put.

Answer (score 1):

This happened due to different version of protobuf jar used. this link will help you understanding the problem
https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=493

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf 2.5 requires that the generated protobuf classes were generated with the 2.5 protobuf compiler. I believe that this error indicates you are mixing the 2.5 protobuf library with generated code from an earlier protobuf version.

I think you're experiencing the same bug described here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9845

To fix this bug, you need to make sure that your generated code matches the protobuf library version. This may require upgrading Hadoop or any other libraries that include protobuf generated code.